# gvim not highlighting searched word where cursor is located

Tags: search, vim, highlight

I just switched to vim 9.0 in Windows and I'm getting a behavior with text search highlighting that seems to be specific to version 9.0 (it wasn't there in 8.2). If I highlight a searched term in gvim, multiple instances of that term will show up highlighted, **except** for the instance where my cursor is.

In the following screengrab, the cursor is on the searched word in the first line, and its inverse red highlighting disappears:

[image: gvim screengrab #1].

When I move the cursor to the next line, the missing highlight switches to line 2:

[image: gvim screengrab #2].

This is very annoying. If I do a complicated search with wildcards, having the text highlighted where my cursor is shows an immediate visual indicator of whether the search is successful or not. Without this, I'd have to look for an error message at the bottom of the window.

How can I disable this weird behavior and have the highlight show up on the searched text where the cursor is currently at?

Comment: Vim 9.0 ships with a new highlight group `CurSearch` and remade built-in colorschemes. By default `CurSearch` is linked to `Search` so the `fox` under the cursor should look just like the other `fox`es. What colorscheme are you using? If it is a built-in one consider opening an issue in https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/issues. If it is not, consider notifying its maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to the color scheme. I'm using koehler but I call it in my vimrc before running a few other color settings:

:set colorcolumn=80

:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=grey20

:hi clear SpellBad

:hi SpellBad term=underline cterm=underline gui=undercurl guifg=NONE guibg=NONE

If I set koehler after these calls, then the highlight problem I had disappears!

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) for overriding colorschemes properly.

Comment: I've followed the suggestions to make changes to my vimrc that makes me happy now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching fix for this issue too. For now I find, that trouble connected with colorscheme. Try :colorscheme %your scheme%. For me it fix this problem. But I didn't find how to fix it without hand set.